# Error installing rpy2 2.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 from a downloaded source archive 'rpy2-2.2.1.tar.gz'. I have been following the installation instructions provided from the rpy2 [documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/overview.html#installation). This is what I am doing:

```
    tar -xzf rpy2-2.2.1.tar.gz
    cd ~/Desktop/rpy2-2.2.1
    python setup.py build install
```

And here is the output in terminal of the attempt:

```
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests_rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Device.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_EmbeddedR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Sexp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpClosure.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpExtPtr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVectorNumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/conversion.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/environments.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/functions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/help.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/language.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/methods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/numpy2ri.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/packages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/robject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/vectors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testArray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testDataFrame.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFormula.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFunction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testHelp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testLanguage.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testMethods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testNumpyConversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPackages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRObject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRobjects.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/process_revents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
    copying ./rpy/interactive/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
    running build_ext
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
    R was not built as a library
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 441, in <module>
        [os.path.join('doc', 'source', 'rpy2_logo.png')])],
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "setup.py", line 152, in finalize_options
        config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
      File "setup.py", line 312, in get_rconfig
        rc = RConfig.from_string(rconfig, allow_empty = allow_empty)
      File "setup.py", line 272, in from_string
        + '\nin string\n' + string)
    ValueError: Invalid substring
```

in string

Answer (score 1):

If the `make` command is missing, chances are you need to install the Apple Xcode Developer Tools.  There should be an installer for Xcode 3 somewhere on the DVD or other material that came with your Mac or copy of OS X 10.6.  Or you can download it from the Apple Developer Connection website (free membership required).  Or you can purchase Xcode 4 from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I am receiving the same error.  But I am using the Easy_install.  The Setup.py is what is generating the error.  I only got a brief chance to examine the setup.py file last night, but I think I have figured it out.

This is what I am pursuing right now.  The newest version of R, 2.13.1, appears to have added an additional directory layer to the R_Home Path.  I suspect that the setup.py for the rpy2 is not expecting this difference and is not able to get past it.  I will be investigating this today.

If it is the case, then I will follow this answer up with my actual fixes and the changed setup.py file.

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the same problem and I have no idea how to solve it...